# Triggers in Loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

I have created a small application in `loopback` in which i was saving user email and password , password in the form of simple text.

Now we have got feature request , to save password in some encrypted format , say , `Base64`.

So what i want is whenever new user created save password in encrypted format , which is easy , which we can do it.

But issues comes we have created users from many different different code locations, so instead of updating code every place is it possible to add some form of `trigger` on `password` field , so whenever this field gets updated , will call a function , which will take password text , and update the same with encrypted format.

so we don't have to worry about writing code everyplace.

Let me know if the question is not clear.

I am looking for Loopback solution.

Thanks

Comment: **Warning! Base64 is NOT encryption!**, just encoding. Please don't store a password like that because the security of your users will be compromised (you are actually storing the password in plaintext). Instead use bcrypt(). LoopBack already stores passwords in encrypted form, but if you do need to store other passwords please do some research on how to safely do so before implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of loopback Operation hooks?

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html

use the `before save` hook or `after save` hook on a model to do what ever you want.

they have an example, you can try it out

Answer (score 0):

If you use default user model, password is by default stored in encrypted form.

If you want custom trigger than you can do it using remote or operation hooks.
Operation Hook: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html
Remote Hook: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

The password is stored in encrypted form. You can use operation hook.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question in the spirit and then in the letter .
Triggers are database level feature where as loop back is your server framework .Keeping that mind your best opportunity within loopback is to use Operation hooks like earlier answers suggested .

However ,if you insist on trigger then you need to use the drivers supported by the DB. In case of oracle there are nodejs-oracle and loopback-oracle connector .If you are using mongo ,which i assume you do , then you may use [mongodb oplog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-oplog) which will give you life cycle method  where you can hook your desired code .For performance reasons i wouldn't recommend such trigger solutions . 
It is not clear from your question what different different code locations means .I assume it is diff parts of your application which might not be loopback .In which case ,putting an entry in a queue and handle it via a processor  will be your best bet sothat you can solve the problem of multiple origin .